# uWSGI processes lose Django sessions

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I just wasted several hours without a real solution, here is the problem:
I log into Django admin and immediately or after few clicks I am thrown out.

I looked for a while in all the settings and configs. The only clue so far is from uwsgi log files, for example:

```
www.example.com [pid: 20047|app: 0|req: 1120/2060] 217.9.101.34 () {42 vars in 841 bytes} [Thu Jul 18 15:27:35 2013] GET /admin/ => ...
www.example.com [pid: 20047|app: 0|req: 1122/2063] 217.9.101.34 () {40 vars in 786 bytes} [Thu Jul 18 15:27:37 2013] GET /admin/auth/ => ...
www.example.com [pid: 20047|app: 0|req: 1124/2066] 217.9.101.34 () {40 vars in 801 bytes} [Thu Jul 18 15:27:39 2013] GET /admin/auth/user/ => ...
www.example.com [pid: 20047|app: 0|req: 1125/2067] 217.9.101.34 () {40 vars in 740 bytes} [Thu Jul 18 15:27:39 2013] GET /admin/jsi18n/ => ...
www.example.com [pid: 19082|app: 0|req: 947/2072] 217.9.101.34 () {42 vars in 841 bytes} [Thu Jul 18 15:27:41 2013] GET /admin/ => ...
www.example.com [pid: 20047|app: 0|req: 1128/2081] 217.9.101.34 () {42 vars in 841 bytes} [Thu Jul 18 15:27:44 2013] GET /admin/auth/
```

The first few requests have the same process ID, that's where I'm logged in. Then another process takes on my next request and apparently this process doesn't know about my session and I'm logged out. The next request has the original ID again but then my cookie was reset already.

I already tried everything: settting up the project again, settings up uwsgi config again, checking nginx, restarting everything, but nothing helps. It can also not be a cookie error because it appears on several browsers on several computers. And after all, the cookies are set and the session gets logged to the database.

Stack is Django 1.5.1, Python 2.7, virtualenv, buildout, MySQL 5.5, nginx, uwsgi, Ubuntu 12.04

Any ideas?

Edit:

This is the uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
#vhost = true  # tried to see if that helps
plugins = python
socket = /tmp/example.com.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 8
cheaper = 2
max-requests=1000
reload-on-rss=110
vacuum=True
harakiri=20
buffer-size=16384  # added to try if that helps
wsgi-file = /var/www/blabla/.../django.wsgi
virtualenv = /var/www/blabla
chdir = /var/www/blabla/...
touch-reload = /var/www/blabla/.../django.wsgi
```

Comment: Use gunicorn. Best thing there is.

Comment: Are you doing anything particular with authentication or middleware in your Django app, or just the standard stuff?

Comment: @DanielRoseman just the standard stuff, it also worked for me for days while other users complained, and now when testing I get this error often...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default, django stores sessions in database, so your problem is most likely due to this bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20537

consider updating to uwsgi >= 1.2.6

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your SESSION_ENGINE ? for example if you set it to use the django caching and set it to locmem:// you will have this kind of problems

Another (possible even if hard to happen) problem (if you are in --lazy/--lazy-apps mode) could be a process with an old copy of the code, have you tried reloading the whole instance ?

Comment: I have not changed SESSION_ENGINE from the default. I also tried turning lazy mode on and off to see if that does something, but it does not. I also stopped all uwsgi processes and started them several times.

Comment: that hostname before each logline is a bit suspicious: are you in virtualhosting mode ? if yes, is it possibile you load the application on-demand ? if yes, are you sure all of your modules are multiple-interpreters friendly ?

Comment: What do you mean on demand? I just place the uwsgi config, and do service uwsgi start.

Comment: i have just seen your config, all is right, just to be sure: which version of uWSGI are you running ? and can you run a "ps aux" on the server to check if there are uwsgi processes running (after a stop) ?

Comment: I have the Ubuntu package: 1.0.3+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1, after a stop, sometimes processes keep running and I need to do killall... I'm aware that this seems to be known bug on Ubuntu

Comment: damn 1.0.3 is really ancient :) i do not think it is related, but generally you'd better to use a stable version (1.4 or 1.9). I would upgrade asap (maybe you hit a corner case bug, we are talking of a release of more than 2 years ago)

Comment: I've updated uwgi to the latest version via pip and now the problem seems to be gone. Do you want to submit this as another answer, so I can accept it?